# upgrade button for 19.10 still not working

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

On ubuntustudio19.04, some 2 months after its release, the upgrade button on the software updater still doesn't work. Hints?  Clues?

Comment: Are we talking 19.10 or 19.04?

Comment: Check with software updater to be sure it is set to notify you of a new release.

Comment: yes, that's how I have it in settings, I have ubuntustudio19.04 and the software updater informs me that 19.10 is available with an upgrade button, but clicking it does nothing

Comment: Make sure your system is completely updated, and use terminal commands.  This link should give you the commands you need.  https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-0417-04-to-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: thanks for that, what you have suggested fails with; 
$Checking for a new Ubuntu release
$Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading
but I've already done that...weird